# Republishing (with illustrations) a copyrighted book with permission

Tags: copyright

I am a high school teacher and would like to approach the publisher of a copyrighted translation of a classic book about republishing it, this time with (public domain classic paintings as) illustrations. I understand this can be done by paying a fee. The publisher is a large, well-known university press, and has all the standard forms online for republishing excerpts and the like, but of course not for this request.

Has anyone here successfully done this? Does anyone know whether this is something I should ask the general 'permissions@...' email?

Comment: I don't think much bad could come from just emailing them. If it's not the right email, it's likely they'll helpfully point you in the right direction, or even forward it to the right one.

Comment: I've never tried to do anything like this. But as @towr says, it doesn't hurt to ask. If they say, "Sure, the license fee will be only $20 million", then (assuming you don't have that kind of money) you say thank you for the information and give up.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll do that. I guess I was hesitant thinking they might just dismiss such an outlandish request.